# Angular Directive access internal ng-model controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have a custom wrapper directive for angular-moment-picker. I use cutrom model attribute (dp-model) and an internal ng-model (dpModelObject). I want to access this internal model controller for set its pristine and validity attributes.

Is it possible?

```js
(function() {

   angular.module('app').directive('datePicker', datePicker);

    datePicker.$inject = [];

    function datePicker() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
              scope: {
                  dpModel: '=',
                  dpRequired: '='
              },
              // replace: true,
              templateUrl: template.html,

              link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ngModelCtrl)
              {
                  if ($scope.dpModel) {
                      $scope.dpModelFormatted = moment($scope.dpModel, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY. MM. DD.');
                  }

                  $scope.$watch('dpModelObject', function(date) {
                      if (date) {
                          $scope.dpModel = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                      }
                  }, true);
              }
      };
 }

})();
```

```html
<div class="input-group datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
        moment-picker="dpModelFormatted"
        ng-model="dpModelObject"
        ng-required="dpRequired"
    >
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the `require` property inside your Directive Definition Object.

From the docs:

> Require another directive and inject its controller as the fourth argument to the linking function.

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel', // here
    scope: {
       ngModel: '=', // and call it by the attribute name
       dpRequired: '='
    },
    ....
```

Then the 4th argument in your link function will refer to the `ngModelController`, [the official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) go over this in more detail